# rspec given, ActiveRecord not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec

Having some problems testing a message broker with rspec given. cant seem to figure out why im receiving this error.

```
 Failure/Error: Given(:profile){ Broker.profile }
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Profile
```

But when using pry i have no problems, here is the code.

```
def profile
  @profile ||= begin
    Profile.find_by_name!(name)
  end
end
```

test with rspec given

```
describe '.profile' do
    context 'checks for instance variable or finds by name' do 
      Given(:profile){ Broker.profile } 
      Then { expect(profile).to be_kind_of (Profile) }
      Then { expect(profile.name).to eq  Broker.name }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just guess, but using pry, You checked test database, or development? Maybe try to save profile to test db before context in rspec starts, so later You will be sure, that it should be found.

Comment: create a profile record with broker name before `Given(:profile)`